# Determine if relative or absolute path in shell program

Tags: linux, shell, path

As stated in the title, I need to determine when a program is ran if the path is relative or absolute:

```
./program #relative
dir/dir2/program #relative
~User/dir/dir2/program #absolute
/home/User/dir/dir2/program #absolute
```

This are my test cases. How exactly could I go about doing this in a shell program?

Or more generally, how to check if a path, `$0` in this case, is relative or absolute?

Comment: The shell will resolve `~` before it runs the script, so you only need to check for a leading `/`

Comment: @user123444555621 - only if it is provided as is.  In case  of echo "~User" it will not.
Update: sorry, I've checked the initial question, it was about '${0}', so this is not the case for tilde.

Comment: @loshadvtapkah If you quote the expression then it means *literally* the relative path in the directory `./~User` -- if that's not what you mean, then the quoting is completely a red herring.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
if [[ "$0" = /* ]]
then
   : # Absolute path
else
   : # Relative path
fi
```

Comment: why do you put [[ ]].

Comment: @DragosRizescu - With `[`, I would have to escape the asterisk.  With `((` the asterisk would stop working at all.  The point is, you don't want to match the asterisk against files that happen to exist in your root directory; you want to match it against the other argument of the equals operator.

Comment: For zsh single = doesn't work. I had to use the [[ "$0" == /* ]]

Comment: @pawcik - Apparently, the OP and myself are bash users.  csh, zsh and some others differ from Bourne shell and bash in using the double equals sign (`==`) for comparison, because the single equals sign is taken by the assignment operator.  This question might need a more specific tag.

Answer (score 21):

A general solution for any `$path`, rather than just `$0`

#### POSIX One Liner

```sh
[ "$path" != "${path#/}" ] && echo "absolute" || echo "relative"
```

Answer (score 7):

```
case "$directory" in
   /*)
      echo "absolute"
      ;;
   *)
      echo "relative"
      ;;
esac
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if [ ${path:0:1} == / ]
then
     echo Absolute path
else
     echo Non-absolute path
fi
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to format this code and explain how it works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer]. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5244995)